# Allow only insert once a day in mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I need to do a web app to collect data from different services, and i want to limit every shop to post the data once a day only via a form in php with my sql.

I tried differents thing but they still duplicate or i got errors.

My table looks like that:

```php
$sql = "CREATE TABLE CA(
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    jour DateTime() NOT NULL,
    shop VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    ca_done VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    objectif VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL ,
    objectif_last_year VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL ,
    comments VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL 
)";
```

and the insert i tried looks like that

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO CA (jour,shop, ca_done, objectif, objectif_last_year, comments) VALUES ('$jour','$shop', '$ca_done', '$objectif', '$objectif_last_year', '$comments') " 
 ;
```

i want the shop to be able to post only once a day or update their daily row and not create duplicates.

Comment: Can you change the `jour` column to a `DATE` type instead of `DATETIME`? Then you can make a unique multi-column index on `(jour, shop)`

Comment: Please use prepared statements for your insert. The way it is right now you're vulnerable to sql injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add column to your table `insert_date`, where you will store date of insertion.

Then create insert trigger on that table, where you'll check if particular shop has already inserted anything on that day. Based on that you can prevnt insertion.

Or even better, you can create unique constraint on `shop, insert_date`.

Comment: No need for a trigger, just create a unique index on `(shop, insert_date)`.

Comment: @Barmar Good idea ! Thanks

Comment: Hello thank you it's working.
i just added as suggested :
``` CREATE UNIQUE INDEX uidx_pid ON ca (shop, insert_date)```

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the `jour` column to the `DATE` data type, you can add a unique index:

```
ALTER TABLE CA ADD UNIQUE INDEX (jour, shop);
```

If not, if you're using MySQL 5.7 you can add a virtual column that contains the date part of the `jour` column, and use that in the index.

```
ALTER TABLE CA ADD COLUMN jourDate AS DATE(jour);
ALTER TABLE CA ADD UNIQUE INDEX (jourDate, shop);
```

Answer (score -1):

Thank you! for your help.
So i added insert_date column.
And as  @Barmar suggested i just added:

`CREATE UNIQUE INDEX uidx_pid ON ca (shop, insert_date)`
 it s working